# How to do strong type checking on static methods on object properties?

Tags: typescript

I have two different classes that define their own static methods. All of the methods have the same signature

```js
class MethodClassOne {
   public static methodOne(): Observable<any> => { ... }
   public static methodTwo(): Observable<any> => { ... }
}

class MethodClassTwo {
   public static methodOne(): Observable<any> => { ... }
   public static methodTwo(): Observable<any> => { ... }
}
```

I define a strongly typed object:

```js
let myObj: {
   prop1: string,
   methodOne: () => Observable<any>,
   methodTwo: () => Observable<any>
} = {
   prop1: 'something',
   methodOne: MethodClassOne.methodOne,
   methodTwo: MethodClassTwo.methodTwo
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain when `methodOne` and `methodTwo` properties reference methods from opposite classes. What I mean is:

```js
let myObj: {
   prop1: string,
   methodOne: methodTypeOne,
   methodTwo: methodTypeTwo
} = {
   prop1: 'something',
   methodOne: MethodClassTwo.methodOne,
   methodTwo: MethodClassOne.methodTwo
}
```

Which is expected, since `methodOne` and `methodTwo` properties do not specify a predefined type, but a signature.

I have tried moving the static methods within `static` object as:

```js
type methodTypeOne = () => Observable<any>;
class MethodClassOne {
   static methods: { [key: string]: methodTypeOne } = {
      methodOne: () => { ... },
      methodTwo: () => { ... }
   }
}

type methodTypeTwo = () => Observable<any>;
class MethodClassTwo {
   static methods: { [key: string]: methodTypeTwo } = {
      methodOne: () => { ... },
      methodTwo: () => { ... }
   }
}

let myObj: {
   prop1: string,
   methodOne: methodTypeOne,
   methodTwo: methodTypeTwo
} = {
   prop1: 'something',
   methodOne: MethodClassTwo.methods.methodOne,
   methodTwo: MethodClassOne.methods.methodTwo
}
```

but the compiler still doesn't complain.

Is it possible to prevent `methodOne` property with type `methodOneType` to reference a static method defined in `MethodClassTwo` with type `methodTwoType`?

I would gladly explain further, or provide additional code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system Both of the types are literally the same.

Comment: Problem is that your `methodTypeOne` and `methodTypeTwo` have identical signatures, just names differ. You can asign `methodTypeOne` variable to `methodTypeTwo` variable. What do you actually want to achieve with this?

Comment: Yea, I know they are totally the same. But the methods that are defined in `MethodClassOne` and `MethodClassTwo` serve different purpose throughout the project. Some of the functionalities are defined in a JSON config, so basically I want to prevent what I described above.